# Trouble getting the footer to stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

Having big problems getting the footer to stay at the bottom of the page.

I've decided to add the code to pastebin:

This is the css: http://pastebin.com/uf2c7jLX

This is one of the pages: http://pastebin.com/qpwz22us

The problem is consistant throught the site. What am I doing wrong?

For example, sometimes this happens, some content is hidden by the footer:

[image]

[image]

There is a huge gap between the bottom of the browser view and footer. The image above also shows that the footer is overlaping the content.

About the edit: The second is not what I want either. There is a huge gap between the footer and the bottom of the browser. I want the footer to be at the bottom and if the content is so long that you have to scroll then the footer should not be visible until you reach the bottom of the page. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the view port (screen) which means that it is always visible, or, just at the bottom of the page no matter how long the page is which means that the footer may be below the fold for long pages?

Comment: So that the footer is at the bottom no matter how long the page is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** actually I just saw your screenshots, just change the absolute positioning to relative

Change the positioning of the footer and body and remove margin from the footer:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
/*padding-bottom: 60px;*/
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

footer{
position: relative;
background: cornflowerblue;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;

}
```

here is the fidle http://jsfiddle.net/vFg8j/

another useful resource - sticky footer http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I think the OP wants a page with a minimum height, not a sticky footer, see the updated post.